# Is it possible to input an address to a pointer from stdin?

Tags: c++, windows, interprocess

Not that long ago, I had an idea for some simple inter-process comunication: one process outputs an address to a pointer, I copy that to the input of another process, and that changes the original variable.

I implemented it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool p;
    cin>>p;
    if(p){
        int n;
        n=0;
        cout<<&n;
        cin.get();
            cin.get();
            cout<<n;
        }else{
            int *point,n;
            scanf("%p",&point);
            cout<<point;
            cin>>n;
            *point+=n;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I used scanf because cin complained, and wouldn't compile. I tried to run it, with two processes, but after I launched the second instance, and input the pointer's address, as outputed by the first, it froze. As I only have access to Windows, I have no idea as to whether it got a SIGSEGV, or if it did something completely diferent.

Is it just me trying to change the value of another process's variable that is crashing it, or is it something else that is stopping me?

Comment: This won't work, but there is a Windows API for doing stuff like this - see [ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx)/[WriteProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx) *et al*.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this that way because first process will not have access to the second process' memory address space (in common operating systems, including Windows and Linux).

Comment: ^ In some operating systems, that is. OP's idea would work in MS-DOS

Comment: Thanks, I added it to my answer to make it more precise.

Answer (score 4):

Each process has its own memory, completely separate from that of other processes. A pointer value is meaningless in context of a different process, even if you manage to get it across.